# Delete MacOS Sierra Installer .dmg after Update

Tags: macos

I downloaded the "Install MacOS Sierra.app", it says there I have to move it to /Applications and then run it afterwards to update my OS on local machine.

Now, after it ran through, can I cleanly remove the installer and any related files  [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) offers me? Or are there some mixups with the updated OS Sierra system files?

I don't need the installer to use disk space, but of course don't want to crash my System by accidently removing something from ~/Library or wherever and then stand there with an unusable system.

Anyone already made some experiences with this?

Cheers,
Tobias

Answer (score 2):

OS X Installer files are automatically deleted from Applications as part of the install process. Normally, it shouldn't need moving there, App Store ought to put it there directly as part of the download process.
They are very unlikely to have any 'related files' of the type that AppCleaner could find.

If you did want to keep a copy for the future, then you need to copy it outside Applications before running the Installer.